# cocoa bindings in interface builder with swift

Tags: swift, core-data, interface-builder, key-value-observing

I have a NSManagedObject subclass, a view Controller and a NSTextField.
The value of the textfield is a binding to a managed property of the managedObject.

However Xcode is complaining that it "cannot resolve the entered key path".
When the view is first loaded, the textfield doesn't have the correct value. Editing the textfield does however result in an appropriate change in the managedObject.

My guess is that interface builder doesn't like that the textfield is bound to an optional value (managedObject?.textValue).

What is the correct way to establish a binding to the property of an optional value in a swift-based project?